# Why is my audio so heavily distorted during calls/ meets

Tags: mac, audio, microphone

I've got a MacBook Air early 2015 running Monterey (12.6.3). It randomly started distorting both my mic input and my audio output during any kind of calls or virtual meetings (google meet, discord etc) if it's any help then I use all these services through safari.

The audio output has a lot of static and keeps cutting out and is oddly high-pitched. My mic input also keeps cutting out very frequently (every few seconds) for the people on the other end. sometimes the mic just stops working completely and system preferences don't show any audio being detected. It's pretty unusable.

I tried to check if the mic worked when I wasn't on a call and it didn't but I managed to fix it by turning on dictation in system preferences which fixed it. But it still doesn't work on calls. The speakers work fine off-call.

I tried turning it on and off a couple of times but that didn't do anything either.

Comment: Open Activity Monitor while you're on a call. It could be that your 2-core CPU is struggling with all the processing required. If audio and mic work outside of calls, then it's clearly something to do with the video-through-Safari aspect. You could try another browser: I'd suggest Vivaldi or FireFox, and not Chrome. Not Chrome.

Comment: Pure guess, based on some earlier observations. Launch Audio Midi Setup [Applications>Utilities] & change the Input Format [from anything to anything… 44.1 > 48 or vice versa] Avoid anything higher than 48kHz if offered. There was a time this would serve to just 'jog its elbow' & wake the audio stream. idk whether it still applies to latest OSes.